# Ultra weakly continuous trace on a von Neumann Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a infinite dimensional von Neumann Algebra with a positive, faithful, ultra weakly continuous trace $tr:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to show that $tr$ is strongly continuous?

Comment: If a net converges strongly (by norm I assume) it will also converge ultraweakly, and hence the traces will converge, so ultraweak continuity implies strong continuity. Did you mean it the other way?

Comment: @Conifold: "strongly" likely refers to the strong operator topology, not the norm topology.  It is not comparable with the ultra weak topology.

Comment: Yes, the thing ist that I want to show that $B(H)$ does not have a with a positive, faithful, ultra weakly continuous trace $tr:M→\mathbb{C}$ if $H$ is infinite dimensional. Yesterday talked to my Professor about it and he explained to me how he would do it. The thing is, his prove needed that the trace is strongly continous, which I don't see right now

Comment: You can probably do with strongly continuous on bounded sets. This equivalent to ultraweak continuity. You can find a proof in chapter 7 of Kadison-Ringrose (most likely section 7.2).